# jQuery UI Sortable + Droppable both trigger when dropped on droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list of elements that are sortable and sort fine. I also have a droppable that resides outside of the sortable list. When I drop items on the droppable, it is intended to perform a copy operation, meaning that sorting during this operation is not desirable.

Unfortunately however, dragging a sortable to an external droppable causes sortable.update to fire. Is there a way to have all sortable drag/drop events ignored if a sortable is dragged outside of a given element?

I've gone through all the relevant sortable events, and I can't seem to find any reference to the element the sortable was dropped on, in order to see if they have common parents.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/6yhbG/

Dragging either sortable 1/2 to the droppable causes the `sortable.sort` to fire.

Answer (score 4):

OK finally got to the bottom of it: `sortable('cancel')` needs to be called from `sortable.stop` and I'm simply adding a class to the sortable so it knows whether to cancel itself or not:

```
$('div').droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        ui.draggable.parent().addClass('dropped');
    }
});

$('ul').sortable({
    stop: function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('dropped')){
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
            $(this).removeClass('dropped');
        }           
    }
});
```

With my updated example at: http://jsfiddle.net/6yhbG/1/